# emberjs array binding not auto update

Tags: arrays, binding, ember.js

I try to bind a array from another array's change. but it not work.

The test.js code like this:

```
var App = Em.Application.create();

Item = Ember.Object.extend({
    name: null
});

CompareItem = Ember.Object.extend({
    i: null,
    j: null
});

Row = Ember.Object.extend({
    title: null,
    tds: []
});

// see emberjs.com/documention "changes in arrays"
App.Items = Ember.Object.create({
    items: [
    Item.create({name: "01"})
    ,Item.create({name: "02"})
    ,Item.create({name: "03"})
    ],
    compareItems: function() {
    var tdItems = [];
    var items = this.get('items');
    items.forEach(function(left, i, lself) {
        var cprItems = [];
        items.forEach(function(right, j, rself) {
        var compareItem = null;
        compareItem = CompareItem.create({
            i: i,
            j: j
        });
        cprItems[j] = compareItem;
        });
        var row = Row.create({
        title: "["+i+"]",
        tds: cprItems
        });
        tdItems[i] = row;
    });
    return tdItems;
    }.property('items.@each')
});

App.Input = Em.TextField.extend({
    change: function(evt){
    var items = this.value.split(" ");
    items.forEach(function(item, index, all) {
        if ($.trim(item)!=""){
        var it = Item.create({name: item});   
        App.Items.get("items").pushObject(it);
        }
    });
    }
});

App.Table = Em.View.extend({
    templateName: 'bsc-table',
    items: App.Items.get("items")
});

App.EditTr = Em.View.extend({
    compareItems: App.Items.get("compareItems")
});

App.EditTh = Em.View.extend({
});

App.EditTd = Em.View.extend({
});
// Em.run.sync();
var bsctable = App.Table.create();
bsctable.app
```

The html code like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="ie6"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie7"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie8"> <![endif]--> <!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css?v=2">
  <style type="text/css">
  .border-table {
  border: 1px solid #960; border-collapse: collapse;
  }
  .border-table th,td {
  border: 1px solid #960; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 5px;
  }
  .txtInput {width:50px;}
  </style>

  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="bsc-table">
    <table class="border-table">
      <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>items</th>
      {{#each items}}
      <th>
        {{name}}
      </th>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
    {{#view App.EditTr}}
    {{#each compareItems}}
    <tr>
      {{#view App.EditTh itemTrBinding="this"}}
      <th>
        [{{itemTr.title}}]
      </th>
      {{#each itemTr.tds}}
      {{#view App.EditTd itemTdBinding="this"}}
      <td>
        [{{itemTd.i}}]
        [{{itemTd.j}}]
      </td>
      {{/view}}
      {{/each}}
      {{/view}}
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
    {{/view}}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.Input}}{{/view}}
  </script>

  <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/libs/ember-0.9.8.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

then, If you type "04 05 06" into the text field, except that table will be 6*6， but now it is not. like that compareItems is a new one every time, but the table use the old one when the items changed. how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use array proxy...

http://docs.emberjs.com/symbols/Ember.ArrayProxy.html

An ArrayProxy wraps any other object that implements Ember.Array and/or Ember.MutableArray, forwarding all requests. This makes it very useful for a number of binding use cases or other cases where being able to swap out the underlying array is useful.

A simple example of usage:

```
var pets = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish'];
var ap = Ember.ArrayProxy.create({ content: Ember.A(pets) });
ap.get('firstObject'); // => 'dog'
ap.set('content', ['amoeba', 'paramecium']);
ap.get('firstObject'); // => 'amoeba'
```

Comment: I don't remember if I had see this answer before, but eventually I just use the Ember.ArrayProxy to do so, see http://www.playscala.com/example/bscmin.html

Comment: Thanks! I spent days to bind an array to a templates and it didn't work. Ember.ArrayProxy is the way to go